# django template вывести дочерние объекты

Tags: django

Есть такая модель.

```
# models.py
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False,
                            verbose_name='Имя')

class Group(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False,
                            verbose_name='Название')

class Students(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False,
                            verbose_name='ФИО')
```

Как в шаблоне получить количество всех учеников данного учителя, что-то типа этого:

```
# template.html
{{ teacher.group_set.all.students_set.all|count }}
```

Всё это нужно, чтобы в итоге сделать таблицу

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Главный учитель</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1-А</td>
    <td>Первый ученик</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Второй ученик</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">5-Б</td>
    <td>Третий ученик</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Четвертый ученик</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вскидку в голову приходит написать фильтр:

```
@register.filter
def get_students_count(groups):
    return Students.objects.filter(group__in=groups).count()
```

В шаблоне соответственно:

```
{{ teacher.group_set.all|get_students_count }}
```

Comment: в принципе оно, спасибо. Сам еще организовал через создание в Teacher и Group скрытых полей, содержащих сумму классов и учеников, и обновление их с помощью сигналов.